# Set string as a reference to a case in Libreoffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Every time I type e.g `VALUE1` in any case I want it to be a reference to a case e.g `B1`. So, if `B1` is `25` and I put `VALUE1` in `C2` and `50` in `D2`, when I do `=SUM(A2:Z2)`, `VALUE1` should be treated as `B1` and the output should be 75. Thanks in advance.

I have tried [this](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-set-a-variable-as-a-cell-value/2404), only when I click on `B1` and type `VALUE1` in the range name, typing `VALUE1` on a case won't make it act as `B1`.

Comment: *and I put VALUE1 in C2* - no, no! In order for the value of cell `B1` to get into cell `C2`, you need to enter `=VALUE1` - the equal sign will show Calc that you need to calculate this value, and not treat it as a text string.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You did not ask a question, just gave some statements. What do you want to ask? -- Anyway, since this seems not to be about software development, this is the wrong StackExchange site. Please consider to ask at a more appropriate site in the network. (Or read the documentation of Calc...)